# canOpenURL always return false even if I specify Launch Service Keys

Tags: ios, facebook-messenger, info.plist, uiapplication

I am trying to detect if a specific app is installed and according to the docs, the [canOpenURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl) method could help. Also I am on iOS 11, and according to the docs, for > iOS 9, this is important thing to keep in mind:

> Important If your app is linked on or after iOS 9.0, you must declare
>   the URL schemes you want to pass to this method. Do this by adding the
>   LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key to your app's Info.plist file. If you
>   call this method for a scheme not declared using that key, this method
>   always returns false, whether or not an appropriate app is installed.
>   To learn more about the key, see LSApplicationQueriesSchemes.

Means that in `Info.plist`, I should add something like this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>messenger</string>
</array>
```

So far, so good. But when I try to detect if app is installed, like this:

```
if( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"messenger://"]]){}
```

I still get false... What am I missing here ?

Comment: Are you sure `messenger` is a valid Scheme?

Comment: messenger is installed in your device or not

Comment: If you are trying to detect / open Facebook Messenger, you probably need to use the Scheme format: `<string>fb-messenger-api</string>`

Comment: @DonMag Yeah that was it. It is not messenger, but rather fb-messenger. Thank you guys !

Comment: @Whirlwind - I posted that as an answer so other people who come across your question will see the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook Messenger uses:

```
<string>fb-messenger-api</string>
```

as its URL Scheme.